# Music bot doesn't detect that user is in voice channel

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a music bot called "Potato Music" and it's a music bot. Currently, the bot executes the commands the way I want them to. But once I stopped hosting the bot locally and deployed it on Heroku, there were some bugs starting to pop out.

I have a command called "play" that is supposed to play a song on a voice channel whenever I execute the command. The `play` command has a condition at the beginning of the command to check if the user is already in a voice channel. But after I hosted the bot on Heroku, once I execute the `play` command, it keeps telling me that I'm not connected to a voice channel.

Why is this?

Here is the code I use to check if the user is in the voice channel:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(self, ctx, *, song):
    # Detect if the user is already in a voice channel
    try:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()    
    except Exception:
        pass
    
    voice = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    
    # If the user is not connected in the voice channel...
    if not voice or not voice.is_connected():
        embed = discord.Embed(description='You should be connected to a voice channel to use the `p!play` command.', color=discord.Color.red())

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return
    
    ... # The rest of the "play" command code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace if not voice or not voice.is_connected(): to if not ctx.author.voice or not ctx.author.voice.channel:

Not sure if it will work on Heroku...

Comment: Thanks! It stopped the bug I initially had.

Comment: No problem, Am glad that I helped